# anchor tag not taking my id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to do some operations while clicking the anchor tag, For the purpose I have assigned an id for the tab and I have written click event in jQuery but its not working.

Here my JSP code is:

```
<li><a id="createBtn" href="#service-one" data-toggle="tab">CREATE</a></li>
```

and my jQuery code is:

```
 $("#createBtn").click(function() {
          alert("Inside button click");
            getScenarioName();
        });

        function getScenarioName() {
            alert("Inside Method");
            $.post("./GetScenarioName", {}, function(data, status) {
                $("#scenario").html(data);
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            });
        }
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Suganth A.

Comment: Are you sure tyhe anchor is already defined by the time you attach the event handler?

Comment: Have you included JQuery library?

Comment: Its work fine check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hYs25/)

Comment: yes am sure claudio redi.

Comment: s included , i have placed the events in other place this time its working fine!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

It is working check [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pJRm9/)

Make sure jQuery is included and you are binding events after dom ready

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#createBtn").click(function() {
          alert("Inside button click");
            getScenarioName();
        });

        function getScenarioName() {
            alert("Inside Method");
            $.post("./GetScenarioName", {}, function(data, status) {
                $("#scenario").html(data);
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put the click event in ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#createBtn").click(function() {
          alert("Inside button click");
            getScenarioName();
        });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Azc5d/